# Is Chi-square test okay to use when there's low number of individuals in cells in a large sample (n > 1000)?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, inference

```
    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  tab
X-squared = 61.663, df = 16, p-value = 2.738e-07
```

**R here shows a warning that the approximation is incorrect because of low cell count, what should I do in this situation?**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A warning is not an error report. I don't think the low expected frequencies implied here are really problematic.

Let's first note what should be explicit, which is that the chi-square test result is based on omitting observations that are NA on either variable, which does seem a very good idea. However, the row and column percents presented include NAs, which should not be allowed to confuse the issue.

The calculation is standard and nothing here hinges on your use of R (the displays don't seem very R-like to me, although I am no expert on that). For the table below I used Stata, and digging deeper supports a minute *P*-value for Pearson chi-square of $2.738 \times 10^{-7}$. 3 decimal places for expected frequencies are more than anyone really needs, but such excess of precision is ritual and allows cross-checks of the reliability of code.

```
          observed frequency
          expected frequency

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
                  |                        healthy                       
         severity |     never     rarely  sometimes     mostly     always
------------------+------------------------------------------------------
               no |         1         11         40         65         13
                  |     2.886     16.235     55.079     48.585      7.216
                  | 
             mild |         3         22        107        123          9
                  |     5.861     32.969    111.852     98.664     14.653
                  | 
         moderate |         7         49        174        132         23
                  |     8.548     48.080    163.117    143.885     21.369
                  | 
moderately severe |         5         31         87         57         11
                  |     4.241     23.853     80.923     71.382     10.601
                  | 
           severe |         8         22         50         27          4
                  |     2.464     13.862     47.029     41.484      6.161
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

3 cells with expected frequency < 5

          Pearson chi2(16) =  61.6635   Pr = 0.000
 likelihood-ratio chi2(16) =  57.4826   Pr = 0.000
```

Output like this allows identification of cells with low expected frequencies. I note from Harold Jeffreys, *Theory of Probability*, Oxford University Press, 1939/1948/1961 and Stephen E. Fienberg, *The Analysis of Cross-classified Categorical Data*. Cambridge, MA: MIT Press, 1977/1980 (reissue New York: Springer, 2007) the rule of thumb that expected counts less than 1 are especially worrying. (Rules of thumb that are more paranoid and/or more complicated are also easy to find.) Here the culprits are 3 cells with expected frequencies around 2 to 4 and it's partly a matter of experience that they are not troublesome given a relationship that is overwhelmingly significant at conventional levels.

That said, it is worth flagging that

1. The chi-square test does nothing to respect the ordered (ordinal, graded) character of both variables and in that sense does not use all the information available.
2. The strength of association here is not as impressive as the *P*-value, although then again even a non-professional awareness of depression and diet underlines that many other personal and social factors may be involved. The bar chart in the question does not allow a good focus on the relationship between variables. Here is a token mosaic plot. Note that under independence, tiles would align horizontally, as well as vertically, which clearly is not happening, given the association.

[image]

3. The chi-square test here is just preliminary, establishing that a relationship appears genuine; the deeper question of modelling the relationship remains. A fuller analysis of the data would need to be informed by the associated sciences. Whether depression is predictable from diet or *vice versa* and which way causation runs if it runs at all (why not a feedback loop? even those who are not or do not consult clinicians are aware of the phenomenon of comfort eating...) are hard questions and ideally require yet more data.

Comment: Great discussion. If we condition on the margins (often held to be almost ancillary) then we can randomly sample from tables with those margins and calculate the conditional distribution of the chi-squared statistic (e.g. via Patefield's algorithm). Leaving out the empty NA row (or, equivalently, combining it with another row) we find in this case, the distribution of the chi-squared statistic is [really close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXgIQ.png) to a $\chi^2_{20}$. So under that conditioning, an exact test based on the chi-squared statistic and the usual χ² approximation are almost identical